# SQL Server : trying to send email using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to send attached file from query result using `sp_send_dbmail`

This is my code:

```
declare @q nvarchar(max)
    
select @q = 'select  
                 case when s.mantype = ''99'' then ''Pre-sales'' 
                      when s.mantype = ''44'' then ''idk''
                      when s.mantype = ''77'' then ''Van sales'' 
                      when s.mantype = ''33'' then ''Delivery Person''
                      when s.mantype = ''55'' then ''Manager''
                 end ''mantype''
             from man s '
begin
    select @sub = 'Fire a Test ' + cast(convert(date,getdate()) as nvarchar)              

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @recipients = 'my@email.com',
              @profile_name = 'Profileone',
              @subject = @sub, 
              @body ='TEST' ,
              @body_format = 'TEXT', 
              @query_result_header = 1 , 
              @query  = @q,
              @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
              @query_attachment_filename= 'Report.cvs'; 
end
```

but I'm getting an error :

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

**Note**: when I remove the case in the query and select the column **mantype**, it runs, but when I add the case again, I get the above error.

Comment: You've omitted the `@execute_query_database` parameter and I *doubt* your table `man` exists in `msdb.`.

Comment: And as an aside, you don't need to quote numbers or column aliases.

Comment: @Larnu It runs when I remove the case and I did receive email with the data but I need the case in this report.

Comment: If you remove the `CASE` you have no query...

Comment: @DaleK This is not the issue I got same issue with another query without quote when I use Case.

Comment: @MickeyMan thats why I started my comment with "as an aside" :)

Comment: @Larnu I meant selecting the column without the case.

Comment: Please provide queries to create the table and insert some sample data. IN addition please show us the query which is working for you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, I solved this issue by creating a view with the desired query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).